# In the Magento sales_order_save_commit_after hook why am I getting duplicate items in my order?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento's observer hooks to hook into the order saving process. I'd like to send a web service a message after an order is set to complete and saved.

However I've noticed that the web service often receives duplicate order items.

Here is a simplified version of my code which I know exhibts the problem:

```
<?php 
class Name_Modulename_Model_Observer {


public function sales_order_save_commit_after($observer) {

    // Gets the order which is being saved.
    $order  = $observer->getOrder();

    $status = $order->getStatus();

    if($status != "complete") {
        continue;
    }

    // PROBLEM - The number of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item 
    // in this array sometimes does not correspond with the 
    // The number of items in the basket. 
    $items = $order->getAllItems();

    $itemsInOrder = array();

    foreach($items as $item) {

        $product = $item->getProduct();

        $itemsInOrder[] = $product->name;

    }

    // At the end of the loop $itemsInOrder can contain 
    // multiple name entries for the same line item. Why is this? 

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an order contains configurable products, the collection returned by `$order->getAllItems();`
will contain parent **and** child products resulting in double element count for this product type. It is safer to use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`